# Creating Stored Procedures - SQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Two questions.

I need to create a procedure called SITE_SP, to count the number of records in the 'SHOWSITE' table.

Then I need to run the site_sp procedure to display the number of records in the 'SHOWSITE' table. My guess here is with the EXEC site_sp.

So far, all I have is (I know it isn't correct but that's all I can do, i'm really stuck).
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS site_sp;
CREATE PROCEDURE site_sp
BEGIN
Select * FROM showsite
END;

Any help appreciated. I've asked before but can't seem to get any positive feedback, so I skipped this question and did the others, but this one I just can't solve.

Answer (score 0):

One solution should be to create a temporary table with your result in it:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS site_sp;
CREATE PROCEDURE site_sp BEGIN DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_result;
CREATE TABLE tmp_result SELECT COUNT(*) FROM showsite END//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Hi.thanks for the reply. So there's no way to do it how I stated ? Sorry just this is an assignment, it's the last question I've got left. Teachers just keep telling me to check out x and x website, but it has nothing on the count function, and I really don't understand a bit of it :(

Comment: The COUNT(*) function returns the number of rows in a result set returned by a SELECT statement. So here it simply count all entries in showsite table. [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count)